# Routing to localhost:8081/home not working but localhost:8081/#/home working

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I understand that this is a very basic question but still I cannot get my head around this very simple issue. Here it is.

Using vuejs-router, I tried to route to a page Custom.vue.

Custom.vue

```
<template>
<div>
   <h1>Hello User</h1>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'Custom'
}
</script>
```

In the routes variable I have configured the path as below.

```
const routes = [
  { path: '/', component: HelloWorld },
  { path: '/home', component: Custom },
]
```

**Question:** Now the painful thing that is happening here is, when I try to access the page with `localhost:8081/#/home` the page loads correctly, but with `localhost:8081/home` it does not.

Comment: You'd need to have history mode enabled + setup a basic server entry point:
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have not enabled history mode, you can enable history mode by something like this

```
new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes,
  base: process.env.BASE_URL
})
```